# How to resolve the KLEE installation error? Related to "subprocess.py"

Tags: python, klee

I am installing KLEE with the following instructions from http://klee.github.io/getting-started/

I have come to the Step 04: ./configure --make-llvm-lib

However, when I run the command, the following error shows up:

```
    INFO:Disabling assertions
    INFO:Configuring for Debug build
    INFO:Configuring for LLVM bitcode archive
    INFO:Using llvm-config at.../root/exp/llvm-2.9/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-config
    INFO:Using llvm tool dir.../root/exp/llvm-2.9/Release+Asserts/bin
    INFO:Found "/root/exp/llvm-2.9/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-objdump".
    INFO:Found "/root/exp/llvm-2.9/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-link".
    INFO:Found "/root/exp/llvm-2.9/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar".
    INFO:Found "/root/exp/llvm-2.9/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-nm".
    INFO:Searching for LLVM Bitcode compiler...
    INFO:Found llvm-gcc in PATH.../root/exp/llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9-i686-linux/bin/llvm-gcc
    INFO:Testing LLVM Bitcode compiler.../root/exp/llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9-i686-linux/bin/llvm-gcc
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./configure", line 622, in 
        main(sys.argv[1:])
      File "./configure", line 122, in main
        handleLLVMConfig(pargs, cc)
      File "./configure", line 400, in handleLLVMConfig
        cc = findBitCodeCompiler(llvmToolDir)
      File "./configure", line 482, in findBitCodeCompiler
        if testBitCodeCompiler(llvmgcc, llvmToolDir):
      File "./configure", line 545, in testBitCodeCompiler
        '-o', bitCodeFileName]
      File "./configure", line 220, in runTool
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
        process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It looks like there is a file missing. However, I am not aware of any file that may be used, since I am unfamiliar to KLEE.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04, and have successfully executed the previous steps. I am very grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Due to the incorrect version of llvm-gcc used (x86_64 instead of i386 error)